# How do I run ADB commands to an android emulator inside an android device?

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device

I recently came across this app on my phone that can emulate an android device inside my real (host) android device. I wanted to use this with ADB commands for testing and other stuff, but I'm not really sure how I can do this.

I've tried searching the internet for an answer, but I couldn't find anything. I also tried seeing methods to use ADB on my phone, and still had no luck

Does anyone know how you can do this, whether the ADB shell has to be installed on my phone or not. The software I'm using is called "[Virtual Android - Android Clone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pspace.vandroid&hl=en_GB&gl=US&pli=1)" and my device is a Huawei P30 Pro. I also do have a PC.

Comment: Great question! I'm glad that I was able to help you with your issue. If you find my answer to be the most helpful, I would really appreciate it if you could consider accepting it as the answer to your question. This helps to improve the visibility of the answer, and it lets other users know that this solution worked for you. Thank you for considering my response, and please let me know if you have any further questions or issues!

Comment: If the emulated Android is accessible on IP level you could connect to it using `adb connect`.